# Missing icons in Joomla Admin and front

Tags: joomla, content-management-system

I have got quite a big problem my Hoster is failing to assist or figure out what it is. I have my Joomla website which I worked offline on Wampserver and later uploading it on my online hoster and can't seem to load icons on Firefox and Google Chrome.

I just get all icons replaced with funny numbers in the backend and no social FontAwesome icons on the front. I trust you can help on this one and find the screenshot of the admin area here...[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umEIQ.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umEIQ.png)

Comment: If you are using firefox then you can right click on that particular image location and click on inspect element to know exactly what is causing the issue.

Comment: check manually the urls of missing images, if they load using their direct url or not. Then check if they are indeed present on webserver in the proper location. Then check the permissions and owner are correct.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to try is clearing the Joomla cache and your browser cache if you haven't already tried that.